# Table view deinit not called

Tags: ios, swift3, deinit

I have a normal `table view` in a completely new project , with no extra code. In my storyboard I have 2 view controllers , and a `navigation controller` embedded to `First Controller` . In `First Controller` I have a table view with button and label. I have given `segue` from `cell` button to second controller in storyboard.

What I want to know is when my `deinit` will be called for first `controller`, it is not getting called. I set break point and nothing seems to be working.

When I `segue` back from `second` to `first` it works for `second controller`, because `controller` is `popped`. But what we need to do for running `deinit` in first controller? Do I need to `pop` first `controller` as well from `stack`? Or do I need to explicitly specify `nil` somewhere else ?

Please help me understand the correct concept behind? Please guide me to correct direction on this.

Code-:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // CELL DATA ARRAY

     var data = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // INITIALIZE total tap ARRAY WITH INDEX 0
    }

    deinit {
        print("Deleted")
    }
}

// TABLE VIEW METHODS

extension ViewController:UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    // NUMBER OF ROWS
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    // number of sections
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    // Cell for row

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // deque cell
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.customLabel.text = "Total taps : \(String(data[indexPath.row]))"
        // CALL BACK BUTTON
        return cell
    }

}
```

Custom Cell-:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Outlets

    @IBOutlet weak var customCount: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var customLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    // Cell button action

    @IBAction func countTaps(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Second Controller-:

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    deinit {
        print("denit")
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't show how this first view controller is created. Why do you want this first view controller to disappear; what will be left from your app when it's gone?

Comment: @meaning-matters I know nothing will left , but I was just checking for testing. Is this possible or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use push/present a view controller, the first view controller is not deallocated and you will not see `deinit` called. The amount of memory required by view controllers is negligible, but the benefit of having it there in memory, in the same state that you left it, is significant (e.g. in your example, if you dismiss the second view controller to return to the table view controller, it ensures that it's still scrolled to the exact same place it was before).

In fact, the system maintains a hierarchy of all of the view controllers that have been presented, but have not yet been popped/dismissed. See [View Controller Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheViewControllerHierarchy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH33-SW1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :)